# Can you continuously sync project backlogs with the tool?

Tags: vsts-sync-migrator, azure-devops-migration-tools

I am looking at a scenario where I need to continuously sync parts of a backlog in one project to another project. I can't see a processor that compares source and target WIs and syncs them after first time migration has been done.

Is there such a processor?

Many thanks, Valentin

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The tool supports re-running a migration and only pulling across changes. It is still only one-way and is designed to support migration.

https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools

The intended purpose of this feature is to allow you to migrate many work items over a few weeks while users are still able to access the source. You can then re-run the migration with a special flag and have it pull the small number of changes.

WARNING: For sync you should note that the Source always wins. So if both the target and the source have been updated then the Source will overwrite the source.

Comment: Is this special flag a secret?

Comment: No, just a query.... dont know what I was going on about.

Comment: Thanks, it already works very well, but quite slow. Can you suggest some query? I assume it should have something like LastChange > LastMigration...